# Why isn't my argument passing correctly in dplyr filter?

Tags: r, dplyr

This function exports a single variable from my dataset and writes it to a new CSV file. For some reason, even though I'm filtering for !is.na(ID), I'm still getting a ton of NAs in my data. Everything else is working correctly.

```
  extract_ids <- function(filename,ID,opp) {
  
  #Read in data
  df <- read_csv(filename)
  
  #Remove rows 2,3
  df <- df[-c(1,2),]
  
  #Filter and select
  df_id <- filter(df, !is.na(ID) & gc == 1) %>%
    select(ID)
  
  #String together variables for export file path
  path <- c("/Users/stephenpoole/Downloads/",opp,"_",ID,".csv")
  
  #Export the file
  write_csv(df_id, paste(path,collapse=''))
  
}
```

And the function call:

```
extract_ids(filename = "farmers.csv",
            ID = "rid",
            opp = "farmers")
```

Unlike similar questions, I'm not getting any error code in R. When I specify the column name (rid) manually, it worked. But when I try to pass rid through the ID argument, it seems to work everywhere except is.na(). For instance, Select correctly chooses the "rid" column and ID passes "rid" into my vector "path."

I also tried writing it out is.na(ID) == FALSE with no success.

Comment: You aren't passing a column name, you're passing a string. Try using `filter(df, !is.na(.data[[ID]]) & gc == 1) %>% select(ID)` or calling the funciton without quotes `extract_ids(filename = "farmers.csv", ID = rid, opp = "farmers")` and using `filter(df, !is.na({{ID}}) & gc == 1) %>% select({{ID}})`

Comment: @MrFlick Nice!  I'm interested in how one might do this for an arbitrary number of masked data variables: `extract_ids(filename = "farmers.csv", opp = "farmers", rid, another_id)`.

Comment: you can use the `...` syntax to pass along all uncaptured arguments. Maybe check out: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: @MrFlick I've been into this for a while, and simply got stuck on the filtration criterion using `across(..., ~ !is.na(.x))`.  Debugged it just now!

Comment: @StephenPoole If you want your function to resemble `dplyr`, here's a few modifications you can make.  Write your function header as `function(filename, opp, ...)` verbatim. Then, **replace** `!is.na(ID)` with `across(..., ~ !is.na(.x))` verbatim.  Now, you can call `extract_ids()` and, just as you would with any `dplyr` verb, you can specify any selection of columns you want to filter out `NA`s: `extract_ids(filename = "farmers.csv", opp = "farmers", rid, another_column_you_want_without_NAs)`.

Comment: @Greg I'm getting an 'object not found' error in relation to the filter while using the across(...) method. Also, what should I substitute the ID variable for while using the ... method in select() and c() above? Should I use (.x) or (...)?

Comment: @Greg I've spelled out this question in detail on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68489883/what-is-causing-object-not-found-error-in-filter-with-the-across-function

Comment: @StephenPoole Sorry, looks like I forgot to wrap the `...` in `c()`, namely as: `across(c(...), ~ !is.na(.x))`