# What is causing 'object not found' error in filter() with the across() function?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

This function filters/selects one or more variables from my dataset and writes it to a new CSV file. I'm getting an 'object not found' error when I call the function. Here is the function:

```
    extract_ids <-  function(filename, opp, ...) {
  
  #Read in data
  df <- read_csv(filename)
  
  #Remove rows 2,3
  df <- df[-c(1,2),]
    
    #Filter and select
    df_id <- filter(df, across(..., ~ !is.na(.x)) & gc == 1) %>%
      select(...) #not sure if my use of ... here is correct
    
    #String together variables for export file path
    path <- c("/Users/stephenpoole/Downloads/",opp,"_",...,".csv") #not sure if ... here is correct
    
    #Export the file
    write_csv(df_id, paste(path,collapse=''))
    
  
}
```

And here is the function call. I'm trying to get columns "rid" and "cintid."

```
extract_ids(filename = "farmers.csv",
            opp = "farmers",
            rid, cintid)
```

When I run this, I get the below error:

```
 Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
ℹ Input `..1` is `across(..., ~!is.na(.x)) & gc == 1`.
x object 'cintid' not found
```

The column cintid is correct and appears in the data. I've also tried running it with just one column, rid, and get the same 'object not found' error.

Comment: If you are passing multiple values to across, it should be like `filter(df, across(c(...), ~ !is.na(.x))` so those columns are all in the first parameter. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @StephenPoole I just updated my answer with a solution to your question about **Variable Names in the Filepath**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for omitting this in my [previous suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/121019776) to you. Unfortunately, [your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68476693/why-isnt-my-argument-passing-correctly-in-dplyr-filter) was closed before I could post it as an answer:

> If you want your function to resemble `dplyr`, here's a few
> modifications you can make. Write your function header as
> `function(filename, opp, ...)` verbatim. Then, replace `!is.na(ID)`
> with `across(..., ~ !is.na(.x))` verbatim. Now, you can call
> `extract_ids()` and, just as you would with any `dplyr` verb, you can
> specify any selection of columns you want to filter out `NA`s:
> `extract_ids(filename = "farmers.csv", opp = "farmers", rid, another_column_you_want_without_NAs)`.

## Object Not Found

As [MrFlick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372064/mrflick) rightly suggests in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/121042498), you should wrap `...` with `c()`, so everything you pass in `...` is interpreted as the first argument to `across()`: a single [`tidy-select`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html)ion of columns from `df`:

```
extract_ids <-  function(filename, opp, ...) {
  # ...

  # Filter and select
  df_id <- df %>%
    # This format is preferred for dplyr workflows with pipes (%>%).
    filter(across(c(...), ~ !is.na(.x)) & gc == 1) %>%
    select(...)

  # ...
}
```

Without this precaution, R interprets `rid` and `cintid` as multiple arguments to `across()`, rather than as simply columns named by the first argument (the `tidy-select`ion).

## Variable Names in the Filepath

To get those variable names within your filepath, use

```
extract_ids <-  function(filename, opp, ...) {
  # ...
  
  # Expand the '...' into a list of given variable names, which will get pasted.
  path <- c("/Users/stephenpoole/Downloads/", opp, "_", match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$`...`, ".csv")

  # ...
}
```

though you might want to consider replacing `` match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$`...` ``, which currently mushes together the variable names:

```
"/Users/stephenpoole/Downloads/farmers_ridcintid.csv"
```

In exactly the same place, you might use the expression `` paste(match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$`...`, collapse = "-") ``, which will separate those variable names using `-`

```
"/Users/stephenpoole/Downloads/farmers_rid-cintid.csv"
```

or any other separator of your choice that gives a valid filename.

Comment: This worked well, thank you. Can you tell me how I might change the code if I want to write two separate CSVs for each column specified in the arguments, i.e., rid, cintid? That was my original goal, but I know I didn't specify that within the question.

Comment: @StephenPoole That depends on whether or not you want each of those CSVs to have a row filtered out, where _any_ of the `*id`s are blank.  That is, do you really want the `farmers_rid.csv` to omit rows where the `cintid` is blank, even when the `rid` itself is present?  Or do you want it to only omit those rows where the `rid` itself is blank?

Comment: I would only want to omit rows where rid itself is blank.

Comment: @StephenPoole Hmmm...in that case, you'll want to break up your `...` into variable names just _before_ performing the `dplyr` operations: ```all_vars <- as.character(match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$`...`)```.  Then replace everything afterwards (the `dplyr` workflow and the `path` and the `write_csv()`), with: `sapply(X = all_vars, FUN = function(var){df_id <- df %>% filter(!is.na(.data[[var]]) & gc == 1) %>% select(var); path <- c("/Users/stephenpoole/Downloads/", opp, "_", var, ".csv"); write_csv(df_id, paste(path,collapse=''))})`.  I _think_ that will work, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Sorry to continue to ask questions, but I have one more. When we use all_vars <- as.character(match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$`...`), that becomes a vector of the inputs to '...', correct? I'm confused about how the function(var) knows to pull the arguments from all_vars. Is var a generic name that corresponds to '...'? How does it know that var is pulling from all_vars?

Comment: @StephenPoole The idea is that ```match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$`...` ``` captures (as `symbols`) all the column names you pass to `extract_ids ()`, and `as.character()` turns those names into `character` strings, stored in `all_vars`. For example: calling `extract_ids(filename = "farmers.csv", opp = "farmers", rid, cintid)` gives us an `all_vars` of `c("rid", "cintid")`. Each of those names is then fed sequentially, as `var` into `FUN`, within the `sapply()` call. For each of those names (`"rid"` and `"cintid"`), `FUN` performs the `dplyr` workflow and write the `.csv` for that column name.

Comment: @StephenPoole Put another way, **you're right** when you say _"`all_vars`...becomes a vector of the inputs to `...`"_. Calling ```extract_ids(filename = "farmers.csv", opp = "farmers", rid, cintid)` ``` will give you an `all_vars` of `c("rid", "cintid")`. Calling `sapply(X = all_vars, FUN = function(var){...})` will **iteratively** pass each element of `all_vars` into `FUN`. That is, `FUN = function(var){...}` is executed for each of `var = "rid"` and `var = "cintid"`.  That's the idea behinds `sapply()`: it will perform `FUN` on every element of `X = all_vars`, taking the element as the arg.

Answer (score 3):

If you are passing multiple values to `across()`, you need to collect them in the first parameter, otherwise they will spread into the other parameters of `across()`. Try

```
filter(df, across(c(...), ~ !is.na(.x))
```

Otherwise every value other than the first one will be passed along as a parameter to function you've specified in `across()`